# How do I set custom hostname in docker-compose for each replica

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

I am trying to make a web server cluster using docker compose. I want to identify each container with a custom unique hostname. My docker-compose.yaml looks like below but I am only able to get container id as hostname

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: "/app/main"
    expose:
        - "8080"
    deploy:
        replicas: 3
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
        - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    depends_on:
        - app
    ports:
        - "4000:4000"
```